# In Word 2010 how do I automatically pull in the users name into a table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm in Word 2010 and I have a field called 'Author' in a table and upon opening the document I'd like to put the user in this field. As I'm in a company I'm sure my name is stored somewhere.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a MS Word Document Property Quick Part (Insert > Quick Part > Document Property > Author), it will automatically add the current Word user's name.  This name is usually set during the first time the program is run, but can be modified by going to File > Options > General and changing the User Name in the Personalize your copy of MS Office section.